# align center items after float

Tags: css, css-float, center, vertical-alignment

I am building a website with a mobile first media queries. Once I got to a bigger device (tablet), I had to float my .textcontainer so it would align on the right side of my image.

The float worked to vertically align my content in the middle of the page but I couldn't figure out how to horizontally center my image and my text-content in the middle of the page.

I added a margin-right of 8% to my .textcontainer to make it look center aligned but I am wondering if there would be a better way to align all my content in the center of the page that would be more responsive?

Also, because I used a float, the .mailicon image doesn't center (vertically and horizontally) at the bottom of my page anymore... I need to bring it back to the middle.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="section section4">
        <img src="icons/ML-network.gif" alt="icon3">
        <div class="textcontainer">
        <h1>Ethereum</h1>
        <p class="ultralight">A turing complete platform with numerous <br> pre-optimized smart contract templates. Backed by the security of Ethereum.</p>
        </div>
        <a href="mailto:contact@magicledger.com"><img class="mailicon" src="icons/email-icon%20color.png" alt="mail icon"></a>
    </div>
```

and my CSS:

```
    main img {
        width: 30%;
    }
    .textcontainer {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    margin-right: 8%;  /* ADJUST BETTER... */  
    }
    main .section > * {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(0, -50%);  
}
    main h1 {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 1.8em; 
    margin-top: 0;    
    }
    main p {
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0;    
    }
    .section4 .mailicon {
    clear: both;
    width: 40px !important;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    }
```

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you try to achieve. You want your icon3 and the textbox in the same row, icon3 to the left and the textbox centered? Or under each other both centered?

Comment: I want the icon3 and the .textcontainer beside each other (so floating) and centered vertically and horizontally in the middle of my .section4.
Than, I want my .mailicon to be center at the bottom of my .section4

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display:inline-block;` to the children element (in your case .textcontainer) which abides the `text-align` rules given in parent.

I put iPhone media query also and made the `.textcontainer` to be center aligned.

```css
img {
  width: 30%;
  float:left;
}
.clearfix{
clear:both;
}
.section{
  text-align:right;
}
.textcontainer {
  width: 50%;
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:left;
}
main.section > * {
  position: relative;
  top: 50 %;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}
main h1 {
  text - align: left;
  font - size: 1.8em;
  margin - top: 0;
}
main p {
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0;
}
.section4.mailicon {
  clear: both;
  width: 40px!important;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  .section{
    text-align:center;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="section section4">
  <img src="icons/ML-network.gif" alt="icon3">
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="textcontainer">
    <h1>Ethereum</h1>
    <p class="ultralight">A turing complete platform with numerous
      <br>pre-optimized smart contract templates. Backed by the security of Ethereum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <a href="mailto:contact@magicledger.com">
    <img class="mailicon" src="icons/email-icon%20color.png" alt="mail icon">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: ok I left my HTML as it is and change my CSS. I display: inline-block the .textcontainer and my main image, deleted all the floats, and added this:
.section4 > * {
    position: relative;
    top: 48%;
    transform: translate(0, -50%);

everything is well centered in the middle of the page now except the .mailicon that sticks under the paragraph, on the right side??

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems not work on my computer ( vertically align ).

You can use jQ to do this:

```
 var conWidth = $(".section4").width(),imgWidth =$(".section4 > img").width(),textConWidth = $(".textcontainer").width() ;
    $(".textcontainer").css("margin-right",(conWidth - imgWidth - textConWidth) / 2);
```

For vertically align center, I usually do this:

```
.someclass{
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align:middle;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
    }
```